# AJAX callback doesn't work.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've tried to make simple callback, so I can get used to it, but it doesn't work when the page loads.

```
$(document).ready(getVideoId(function (response) {
        alert(response);
    }));

function getVideoId(callback){
var http;
var url = base_url + "main/firstVideo";

if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    http=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject){
    // code for IE6, IE5
    http=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
else{
    alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!");
}

http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", 0);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
http.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        callback(http.responseText);
    }
http.open("POST", url, true);
http.send(null);
};
}
```

Idea is that I will get back video_id from database and make alert out of it. Base_url is defined as a variable.

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Reload the page. What does the JavaScript console say? Can you see your Ajax request in the Net tab? Is it formatted correctly? Does it get a response? Is the response correct?

Comment: You need to pass `ready` a *function*. The return value of your call to `getVideoId` is not a function.

Comment: Why are you using jQuery (`$(document).ready`) but still the native-JS ajax code? Use the jQuery ajax API.

Comment: If you're using jQuery why are you doing Ajax stuff manually?

Comment: Why are you making a POST request with a zero length body to *get* data?

Comment: Is `base_url` declared anywhere?

Answer (score 4):

You're only opening the AJAX request from its own callback, which will never fire.

```
http.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        callback(http.responseText);
    }
}; // << close the function here
http.open("POST", url, true);
http.send(null);
```